# Mouse Configuration - Where to configure special mouse button to perform some compiz actions?

Tags: compiz, mouse, cube

I've updated to 11.04 and I now need to reconfigure a lot of things. One of them is the mouse "special "buttons.

Before I clicked on the red button that my mouse brings, and I switched desktops.

I tried to do that again, but on the Compiz configuration we can see this useless information like:

Button1

Button2

Button3

Button4

and so on...

I have no clue about what number is associated with my red button of this Microsoft Optical Comfort 3000 mouse.

Where can I configure mouse buttons/clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only program I know of that I use to figure this stuff out is called `xev`.  Run it from the command line (Terminal):

```
$ xev
```

Then you will get a pop-up box.  [image]

In that "Event tester" box, click your buttons, you will see button down and button up events show up in the terminal window. Each event will have a button number associated.  Keep clicking them till you determine which one is which.

Pretty handy utility.